# How to extract strings from a c++ string using regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I'm using regex by using `#include <regex.h>` If I have a string s, how can I use regex to search for a pattern p?

Comment: Which regex.h? The Unix one? You should better specify that, since it's not a standard C++ or C header.

Comment: I'm just using the one that's already there, so the default, whatever that is. I'm in OSX, which is basically the same as Linux.

Comment: What is your compiler and OS? Anyway, if you want cross-platform and cross-compiler compatibility and a good OO interface, I suggest trying Boost.Regex. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I'm in OSX and I'm using g++.

Comment: You have two very different regular expression libraries available to you. `#include <regex.h>` is the C library, standardized by POSIX.1-2001. `#include <regex>` is the C++ library standardized in C++ TR1. You will probably find the C++ regular expression library more useful.

Comment: I don't think I have the other library. `#include <regex>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string
match(const char *string, char *pattern)
{

// Adapted from:
   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html

    int    status;
    regex_t    re;
    regmatch_t rm;


    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
        return "Bad pattern";
    }
    status = regexec(&re, string, 1, &rm, 0);
    regfree(&re);
    if (status != 0) {
        return "No Match";
    }
    return std::string(string+rm.rm_so, string+rm.rm_eo);
}

int main(int ac, char **av) {
    // e.g. usage: ./program abcdefg 'c.*f'
    std::cout << match(av[1], av[2]) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982821.aspx, has detailed usage patter for regex. from MS vc blog.

```
      const regex r("[1-9]\\d*x[1-9]\\d*");

      for (string s; getline(cin, s); ) {
               cout << (regex_match(s, r) ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
      }
```

Comment: That details the usage of `<regex>`. The OP asked for an example of `<regex.h>`. They are not the same API.